# Choose best image size from a list for given screen dimensions

Tags: algorithm, graphics

Given the following possible screen sizes:

```
720x480
1280x720
1920x1080
3840×2160
```

And a range of image sizes similar to the following (which may vary to some degree, and the maximum size can be anything up to the limit of available memory):

```
Square          75              75
Large Square    150             150
Thumbnail       100             75
Small           240             180
Small 320       320             240
Medium          500             375
Medium 640      640             480
Medium 800      800             600
Large           1024            768
Large 1600      1600            1200
Large 2048      2048            1536
Original        3264            2448
```

And that some images may not be available in "Original" size and may not be larger 1024x768

I need to choose the best image for the current screen dimension.

I'm unsure how to approach this. The language will be Brightscript, but I'm really looking for a selection algorithm, or at least some suggestions on how to write the selection algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to choose the best image for the current screen dimension

It depends on what one means by "the best". One could try to optimize for width, others for height, or trying for the both at the same time (that would be trying to minimize the remaining area ). Let's optimize the remaining area. Here's a pseudo-code:

```
given screen s0
initialize best_image := None
           best_remaining_area := INF
for image in image_list:
     if s0.height < image.height or s0.width < image.width:
         continue
     remaining_area  = s0.height * s0.width  - image.height * image.width 
     if remaining_area < best_remaining_area:
         best_remaining_area = remaining_area
         best_image = image
 return best_image
```